# Flutter CloudFirestore adding complex types throws Invalid argument: Instance of 'Team'

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have class Match that has a list of other classes of type Team. Upload of new document (Match) to Firestore is only possible if the list is empty. Once there is Team item in the list, attempt to add it to Firestore throws '**Invalid argument: Instance of 'Team'**'. Team class only contains simple fields, no other classes.

Exception is thrown from StandardMessageCodec.writeValue

**Update:**
I am using cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2, and calling

```
await firestore.collection('matches').document(match.id).setData(match);
```

since there is no other method that would allow for upload other than setData (accepting Map), I have tried for  match.teams (List):

1. 'teams' : teams (List)
2. 'teams' : encode to json completely (String)
3. 'teams' : encode individual Team items and add to collection (List)

1st option will fail, second will create a single string document member and third will create an array of strings inside member, none of which is what I want - create an array of team objects inside document

Comment: You can't store classes in Firestore, only JSON. https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: the processing StandardMessageCodec.writeValue does have handling for type List as well, I thought it supports such data structure. I will try to flatten it to json

Comment: Sure, list is supported in JSON, but not custom classes within that list.

Comment: this does not work the way I would like it to work - if I serialize entire list, it will create a single string member in the document, if I serialize individual items and create a list of those, it is an array of strings in Firestore's document;

Comment: just figured it out, I should have made it into a list of Map, not flatten it to jsons; thanks Gunter for leading me to the answer

Comment: List of Map is considered JSON. What you mean is probably a serialized JSON *String*. That's not necessary because Firebase does that serialization itself, but the value needs to be serializable and Firebase doesn't know how to serialize your custom class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To Completely solve the above problem, follow the following steps:

Steps:

1. Use json_serializable plugin (link: https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable)
2. At the following class level json_serializable annotation to your Match class (note the options)

   part 'match.g.dart'; //actual file will be automatically generated

   @JsonSerializable(anyMap: true, explicitToJson: true)
3. Do the same(in 2 above) for your Team class(you can ignore the option: explicitToJson):

   part 'team.g.dart'; //will be automatically generated

   @JsonSerializable(anyMap: true)
4. in your terminal or console (at the root of your project), run: **flutter pub run build_runner build** to generate all the necessary: *.g.dart files (i.e. match.g.dart, team.g.dart) for your serialized class files

   [pc-name]:[project_root_dir] [username}$ flutter pub run build_runner build

I really hope this helps solve your problem completely as it did mine.

Reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: Cheerio! Adding @JsonSerializable(anyMap: true, explicitToJson: true) worked!

Answer (score 2):

After help from Gunter that pointed to me that such data composition is not supported, I figured it out - List of specific objects needs to be transformed into a List of Map